# how to gzip and scp at the same time

Tags: ubuntu, bash, shell, centos, bash-scripting

I have a file in which i wanted to zip up and at the same time transfer over to another host using scp.

I tried to do the following command but failed.  I do not mind zipping up and scp over later, but i just want to know where did I got it wrong

Am i wrong to use a pipe | over here ?

```
-bash-3.2$ gzip -c aum.dmp | scp oracle@192.168.0.191:/export/home/oracle/aum.dmp.gz
Usage: scp [-pqrvBC46] [-F config] [-S program] [-P port]
           [-c cipher] [-i identity] [-o option]
       [[user@]host1:]file1 [...] [[user@]host2:]file2
```

Regards,
Noob

Comment: if you specifically know the file name beforehand (and do not need to automate this), then you better skip the pipe and make sure to wait for gzip to (successfully) finish: `gzip -c file.dmp && scp file.dmp.gy user@host:/path/to/file`. Note that your command is missing the source file for the whole copying action.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

gzip will write to STDOUT, and scp can't handle it.

try

```
gzip -c aum.dmp | ssh -l  oracle 192.168.0.191 'cat > /export/home/oracle/aum.dmp.gz'
```

instead.

where

- `gzip -c aum.dmp |` will gzip aum.dmp, and send result to stdout
- `ssh -l oracle 192.168.0.191` will connect to user oracle on 192.168.0.191
- `'cat > /export/home/oracle/aum.dmp.gz'` will execute this command

'cat > /export/home/oracle/aum.dmp.gz'

- `cat` will capture stdin (stdout from command before | )
- `> /export/home/oracle/aum.dmp.gz` will write to this /export/home/oracle/aum.dmp.gz

the whole purpose of cat part, executed n remote site is to capture gzip result.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, i do not understand the last portion of the whole command , what does the  ' '  meant ?  so instead of scp, are we using ssh instead then ?

Comment: yes, scp can't handle STDIN/STDOUT but ssh can.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `-C` flag to enable **c**ompression in `scp` transfer. This should be enough, although you can check [`man scp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) for more details on compression.

Comment: this will compress data on network, saving bandwith, it will not compress file.

Comment: Using -C flag will make the process slower than normal - https://serverfault.com/q/697363/151023

Answer (score 9):

In case you need to get the files/directories from a remote server, into a local archive, you can use **tar + gzip** inside ssh, and redirect to a local file. For example:

```
ssh user@server "sudo tar cvzf - /var/log/containers/**/*.log" > containers_logs.tgz
```

Where:

- c - create archive file.
- v - show the progress.
- z - compress with gzip.
- f - filename of archive.

Comment: I think this is the best approach.